# Can i Delete Few HTML Tags in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

In my HTML code i want to check the following HTML code and automatically delete it on page load, how do i do it in JQuery ?

First Code that needs to be deleted

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr class="yellow"><td width="64%" valign="top">
```

Second Code that needs to be deleted

```
</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Yes i tried but its deleting the whole contents under table tag i do want to delete only specific tags

Comment: append the child you want to keep to somewhere else in the document, and then delete the undesired table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want to remove whole table, want to just remove the tags

You can't remove ‘tags’ from a live HTML document. A document living in a web browser is a tree of DOM ‘nodes’. The nodes maintain the current state of the document, and were originally parsed from the tags in the HTML source. But that markup is now gone and cannot be recovered(*) or edited in the browser.

So you have a node representing the `table` element, containing nodes for all the content between the `<table>` start-tag and the corresponding `</table>` end-tag. In this case that's one `tbody` element node, which contains one `tr` element node, which contains one `td` element node.

To ‘unwrap’ the inner content you will need to take it out of the table and drop it in the place the table is. You can do this in jQuery using:

```
$('#mytableid td').eq(0).contents().replaceAll('#mytableid');
```

That is, replace the table with everything in its first cell.

(*: you can read `innerHTML` to get a string of markup from a DOM element node, but this serialisation is newly-generated markup and won't typically be *exactly* the same as what you put in.)

Answer (score 1):

If you put an `id` or `class` attribute on the `table` tag, you can use the jQuery `remove()` function to completely remove the element and its contents from the DOM:

`$('#yourTableId').remove();`

Comment: Well please note that i dont want to remove other Tables under it so just the tag

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"><tbody><tr class="yellow"><td width="64%" valign="top"> needs to be removed

Comment: Do you mean that there is some content inside that `td` element that you want to keep as it is?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from your statement, you need to delete tables from page. For that,

```
$('table').remove();
```

will work. However if you give a `<table id='xxx'...` then it will be more convenient to use

```
$('table#xxx').remove(); // or just $('xxx')..
```

Comment: I dont want to remove whole table tag want to just remove the tags which are mentioned 1 and 2

Comment: You can't delete tags and leave the content there. It is HTML, everything is enclosed in some element, and if you delete element tag, all its children also be removed.